# mailcore2 setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeClear

Tags: mailcore2

mailcore2 setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeClear，can’t get mail！！！！what is matter？

```
//initialize the session
self.session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];

[self.session setHostname:@"xxxx"];
[self.session setPort:xxxx];
[self.session setUsername:@"xxxxx"];
[self.session setPassword:@"xxxxxx"];


[self.session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeClear];
MCOIMAPOperation *op=[self.session checkAccountOperation];
[op start:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

this block is not callback

Comment: Maybe you're just getting a timeout after a couple of minutes.

Comment: Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo=0x7fc24143c5e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.}

Comment: You're using wrong connection parameters. Please try to give more insight about your issues. You're so brief that I barely understand what your issue is.